# How to implement a web login using a public/private key pair?

Tags: authentication, cryptography

I am trying to create a web form, where the user can login without creating/entering a password.

Assume the following pre-requisites are met:

1. The user and server have pre-generated a public/private key pair (on curve [ed25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/)).
2. The user and server both know each others public keys.

A simple protocol might look like this:

1. The server generates some random text.
2. User signs this text and posts the signed data to the server. (Assume this is done via a normal HTTP POST request on a SSL connection).
3. The server verifies the signature, and grants access if the signature is verified.

Is this protocol secure? If not, what is a good secure protocol which guarantees similar security as using a password?

Comment: So, basically, re-invent client-side certificates?

Comment: @LjmDullaart Yes, however the user also uses the certificate(private key) for signing other things necessary in the app.

Comment: Why would it be vulnerable to replay attacks? Does the server issue the same challenge document each time?

Comment: @nobody Is the scheme secure then if the server always generates random data? I have edited the question to phrase this better.

Comment: The scheme you provided doesn't prevent impersonating the client, the client can be used as a signing oracle.

Comment: @gkpln3 The client needs human intervention for signing, just like entering a password, so impersonation here is not going to be a problem.